# Professional menu with JavaScript and jQuery (The last part)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my previous questions and with the help of Michael M., I fixed all the shortcomings of my site's menu.

But after transferring the menu to my site, I realized that my menu does not open any links and all menu and sub-menu options are only in display mode.

I deleted the following code from the scripts, which was related to deleting the link under the menu, but it still didn't help:

```
   sub_menu.stopPropagation();
```

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".icon_menu");
let nav = document.querySelector(".main_menu");

$('.back').hide();
$('.back').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':hidden')) return;
  $(this).toggle();

  icon.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
  icon.style.left = "2%";
  icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
  icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

  nav.style.left = '-300px';
});

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("bi-grid-fill")) {
    this.classList = "bi bi-x-circle-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "21%";
    icon.style.color = "#ff6f6f";
    icon.style.fontSize = "30px";

    nav.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    this.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "2%";
    icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
    icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

    nav.style.left = "-300px";
  }
  $('.back').toggle();
});


$('.main_menu li ul').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('submenu')
});

$('.submenu').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is($(this).find('ul a'))) { return; }
  
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.main_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #eee;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.icon_menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #a66fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all 1.1s ease;
}

.main_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main_menu ul li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9 !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #00000056;
}

.main_menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.main_menu .submenu>a::after {
  content: ' → ';
}

.main_menu .open>a::after {
  content: ' ↓ ' !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section>
  <nav id="nav">
    <span class="bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu" style="right: 46%; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 80px;"></span>
    <aside class="main_menu" style="right: 0px;">
      <ul id="menu-menu-2" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-48"><a href="#"><span
              class="dashicons dashicons-admin-home after-menu-image-icons"></span><span
              class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">home</span></a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-49 submenu">
          <a href="#"><span class="dashicons dashicons-welcome-learn-more after-menu-image-icons"></span><span
              class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test text</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-78"><a href="#"
                class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                  src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Music-114.ico"
                  class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="36"
                  height="36"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test text</span></a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-82"><a href="#"
                class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                  src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Hardware-Devices-316.ico"
                  class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="16"
                  height="16"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test text</span></a></li>
            <li
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-50 submenu">
              <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                  src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Music-148.ico"
                  class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="36"
                  height="36"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test text</span></a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-77"><a href="#"
                    class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                      src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/button-yellow.ico"
                      class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="16"
                      height="16"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test text</span></a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169"><a href="#">Test
                    text</a></li>
                <li
                  class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-170 submenu">
                  <a href="#">Test text</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-80"><a href="#"
                        class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                          src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Star-27.ico"
                          class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="36"
                          height="36"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test text</span></a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-168"><a href="#">Test
                        text</a></li>
                    <li
                      class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-167 submenu">
                      <a href="#">Test text</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li
                          class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-166 submenu">
                          <a href="#">Test text</a>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li
                              class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-52 submenu">
                              <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                                  src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Hardware-Devices-316.ico"
                                  class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy"
                                  width="16" height="16"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test
                                  text</span></a>
                              <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-79"><a
                                    href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                                      src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Firefox-4.ico"
                                      class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy"
                                      width="36" height="36"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test
                                      text</span></a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-81"><a
                                    href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img
                                      src="https://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Music-161.ico"
                                      class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy"
                                      width="36" height="36"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Test
                                      text</span></a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-163"><a
                                    href="#">Test text</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Many thanks to `Steve`(76484) for completing my code.

This code works perfectly fine in HTML mode, but when I add this code to WordPress, a new problem occurs.

When I introduce the menu to WordPress, only one sub-menu can be added to it. By adding the second sub-menu and clicking on it, all the sub-menus will be closed and no sub-menu will be displayed.

The menu code that I converted to WordPress code:

```
 <section>
        <nav id="nav">
          <span class="fas fa-bars icon_menu"></span>
          <aside class="main_menu">
           <?php
      if ( has_nav_menu( 'top_menu' ) ) {
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
          'menu_class' => 'menu',
          'container' => false
        ) );
      }
      ?>
          </aside>
        </nav>
      </section>
      <div class="back"></div>
```

The code I added to my template `function` file:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'top_navigation_menus' ) ) {

  function top_navigation_menus() {

    $locations = array(
      'top_menu' => __( 'Site menu', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );

  }
  add_action( 'init', 'top_navigation_menus' );

}
```

**I did not change the styles and they are the same as the styles above.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that you need the `.stopPropagation()` or `.preventDefault()` calls in your `.submenu` click handler.

I would just add a guard to that handler that checks whether the `target` of the click was an `<a>` within the `<ul>`, and if so, do not execute the rest of the function body - the opening/closing of the submenu.

**Update**

To prevent the click of the `li.submenu > a` from following the href you would need to add the `event.preventDefault()` back. The snippet below has been updated.

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".icon_menu");
let nav = document.querySelector(".main_menu");

$('.back').hide();
$('.back').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':hidden')) return;
  $(this).toggle();

  icon.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
  icon.style.left = "2%";
  icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
  icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

  nav.style.left = '-300px';
});

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("bi-grid-fill")) {
    this.classList = "bi bi-x-circle-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "21%";
    icon.style.color = "#ff6f6f";
    icon.style.fontSize = "30px";

    nav.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    this.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "2%";
    icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
    icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

    nav.style.left = "-300px";
  }
  $('.back').toggle();
});


$('.main_menu li ul').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('submenu')
});

$('.submenu').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is($(this).find('ul a'))) { return; }
  
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.main_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #eee;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.icon_menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #a66fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all 1.1s ease;
}

.main_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main_menu ul li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9 !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #00000056;
}

.main_menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.main_menu .submenu>a::after {
  content: ' → ';
}

.main_menu .open>a::after {
  content: ' ↓ ' !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav id="nav">
    <span class="bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu"></span>
    <aside class="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">our articles</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">social</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">Academic</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">historical</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </nav>
</section>
<div class="back"></div>
```

**Another Update**

We can simplify all of this by explicitly targeting the first `<a>` within each `li.submenu`. We replace the `.submenu` click handler with:

```
$('li.submenu > a').click(function(event) {
  const $submenu = $(this).parent();
  
  $submenu.children('ul').slideToggle();
  $submenu.toggleClass('open');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

See example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5yckv7zo/).

Comment: Hello. I tested your code. The problem that arises is that <li> links containing <ul> should not be followed. That is, by clicking on <li> where there is <ul>, instead of opening the sub-menu, it goes to the <li> link.

Comment: @Developer : I see. That is what the `.preventDefaultf()` was for. We can add that back to the `.submenu` click handler body. I have updated the snippet to include `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is completely solved.

Comment: @Developer If you put your code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [pen](https://codepen.io/) and share the link, I will get it working. For example, this seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5hargoy2/

Comment: Hello. Yesterday, I thought the problem was with the styles I gave to the menu. That's why I deleted all the styles and wrote them again, but the problem was still not solved. It works fine when the menu is in HTML mode, but when I add it to WordPress, it has problems. In WordPress mode, the first sub-menu works well, but the second sub-menu is opened by clicking for a short time and all the sub-menus are closed immediately... I put my wordpress code in the edit of my question.

Comment: If you add this menu to WordPress and create several submenus for it, you will understand what I mean. Thank you for your time so far.

Comment: @Developer: Wordpress must bre producing different HTML than what we have been assuming. Rather than post the PHP code, can you copy the HTML produced by Wordpress and share that (it should be obtainable in the Page Source or the browser's developer console) ?

Comment: Hello. I edited my question. I put the HTML generated by WordPress.

Comment: @Developer It seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/8v13fspu/ This leads me to believe there is additional JavaScript on your page that is interfering.

Comment: When I open the first sub-menu, it is correct, but when I open the second sub-menu, all the sub-menus are closed. This is completely visible in the fiddle.

Comment: <ul> The first (display: none; ) becomes (display: block;) after clicking, but when you click on the second sub-menu, it gets (display: none; ) and the sub-menu is completely closed.

Comment: In addition, I deleted all the scripts of my site, but there was no difference and this problem still exists.

Comment: Only in the script code, a function should be introduced so that the first (main) submenu is not closed when the second and subsequent submenus are clicked.

Comment: You want the sub-menus to be open?

Comment: No. Just click below to open the menus. But this happens only for the first sub-menu. By clicking on the second sub-menu, all sub-menus are closed.

Comment: Please, in the fiddle you made, after opening the first sub-menu, click on the second sub-menu to understand what I mean.

Comment: By clicking on the second sub-menu, all sub-menus will be closed.

Comment: I have used the plugin (Menu Image). Disabling it solved the problem. But I need this plugin for my website menu. There is no way to correct this interference?

Comment: I think what you are asking for is to ignore clicks on the `<li>` elements. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5yckv7zo/ (Don't worry about the colors, I added them just to help me understand the menus)

Comment: @Developer: The update I made to the answer and included in the fiddle link is a better solution, I believe.

Comment: Yes. This edit worked much better. Thank you very much again.